# When does the derivative along $h$ of $G(0)$ exist?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $G = \frac{|x|^{\alpha} y^{1/3}}{|x|+|y|}$, when $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ and
>   $0$ when $(x,y) = (0,0)$.
>
> For which $\alpha$ does $G'(0;\mathbf h)$ (the directional derivative
>   of $G$ along $\mathbf h$) exist ($\forall \mathbf h\in \mathbb R^2$)?

According to the definition of directional derivative it's equal to the following limit ($h=(a,b)$):

$$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{G(t\mathbf h)}{t} =\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{|ta|^\alpha b^{1/3}}{t(|a|+|b|)}$$

So, the exercise could be solved by showing for values of $\alpha$ for which the limit exists. I think it doesn't exist, so the directional derivative never exists, because the limit of $|t|^\alpha/t$ doesn't exist for any $\alpha$. Am I correct?

Comment: When you are plugging what you should get is  $\frac{G(th)}{t}=\frac{|ta|^\alpha (tb)^{1/3}}{t(|ta|+|tb|)}=\frac{|t|^{\alpha -1}|a|^\alpha b^{1/3}}{t^{2/3}(|a|+|b|)}$

Comment: Right! That was a mistake. Forgot to include the modulus of $t$. Thanks!

Comment: Now, the hint is: Does the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{|t|^\alpha}{t^\beta}$ exist if $\alpha>\beta$?

Comment: Yes, it does tend to 0. So the answer is $\alpha - 1 - 2/3 > 0 $.